# Write output of multiple files to a directory using glob.glob after processing?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, gdal-translate

I want to convert the data type (Int32 to Float32) of all the tiff images in a directory `'F:\\prep\\input\\'` and save/write the outputs to a new directory `'F:\\prep\\converted\\'`.

I have tried using `gdal.Translate` and `glob.glob`:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import glob
import os
data_to_process = glob.glob(os.path.join('F:\\prep\\input\\*.tif'))
for data_path in data_to_process:
raster_dataset = gdal.Open(data_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
raster = gdal.Translate('F:\\prep\\converted\\*.tif', raster_dataset, outputType = gdal.GDT_Float32)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation is off, but I'll assume that's just a copy/paste issue.

Your issue is that `'F:\\prep\\converted\\*.tif'` will try to output a file called literally `*.tif` which won't work.  You need to provide an actual file name.  I suggest using `os.path.join` and `os.path.basename`

Try this:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import glob
import os

input_path = 'F:\\prep\\input'
output_path = 'F:\\prep\\converted'

data_to_process = glob.glob(os.path.join(input_path, '*.tif'))
for data_path in data_to_process:
    raster_dataset = gdal.Open(data_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    raster = gdal.Translate(os.path.join(output_path, os.path.basename(data_path)), raster_dataset, outputType = gdal.GDT_Float32)
```